# How to reset camera position with DeviceOrientationControls on mobile device

Tags: three.js, webvr

I create webvr by three.js and I use DeviceOrientationControls to controls on the mobile device and create recenter button but I don't know how to do it, I can create this function with orbitControls on the desktop by config controls.position to default position but it doesn't work on mobile.

Recenter desktop code:

```
 button.onclick = () =>{
      controls.object.position.set(
        1.2246467992175396e-20,
        1.6,
        0.00010000000002024652
      );
    };
```

Comment: Are you aware that `DeviceOrientationControls` does not change the `position` property of its `object` property? Maybe you want to reset its `rotation` instead?

Comment: I try to reset rotation as this controls.object.rotation.set(x,x,x)  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Now I rotation scene instead and it's work.

Comment: @JutaJumpatong Can you post your solution? Thank you!